# Can't get info out of a MySQL DB, gives error "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Tags: php, mysql

Here's the code:

```
print_table.php:
----------------

<?php

function print_table($db)
{
    foreach ($db->query("SELECT * FROM name_of_db") as $row)
    {
        echo $row['title'];
    }
}

?>

mysql_connect.php:
------------------

<?php

class mysql_connection
{
    private $_dsn;
    private $_user;
    private $_pass;
    private $_db;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_dsn = "mysql:dbname=nope;host=nope";
        $this->_user = "nope";
        $this->_pass = "nope";
        $this->_db = null;
    }

    public function connect()
    {
        try
        {
            $this->_db = new PDO($this->_dsn, $this->_user, $this->_pass);
        }
        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            echo "Connection Failed: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function get_db()
    {
        return $this->_db;
    }
}

?>

init.php:
---------

<?php

include_once("mysql_connect.php");
include_once("print_table.php");

$con = new mysql_connection();
$con->connect();

?>
```

init.php is called at the very beginning of index.php. Then, later in index.php I have this line:

`<?php print_table($con->get_db()); ?>`

Why could that be?

Thank you!

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: From Stack Overflow FAQ: `We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them` - so yeah, next time paste the code in your question :)

Comment: In the future, if your code is throwing an error like that, perform a `var_dump()` on whatever variables are being passed and you'll "instantly" see what's wrong. Debugging is 90% of a developer's job. Writing code is secondary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. The problem was that I was using SELECT * FROM name_of_db, but it should've been the table's name.. Such a stupid mistake.. argh

Answer (score 2):

```
function print_table($db)
{
    $aRows = $db->query("SELECT * FROM name_of_db");
    foreach ($aRows as $row)
    {
        echo $row['title'];
    }
}
```

This fixes the problem. Don't use the `mysql_query` IN the foreach, use the returned value instead

Comment: Shouldn't really matter, php will still take the array from the query result and iterate it.. but the other construct assumes the query succeeded, which everyone should know is not a good thing at all.